# Hierarchical clustering using corclust

Tags: r, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to create hierarchical cluster by using corclust function from klaR package in R. The function is trying to pass the values to the hclust function, but it is not accepting the parameters like mincor, method.

**code**

**plot(corclust(iris[,-5],iris[,5],mincor=0.5))**

While running the above line am getting the following error.

**Error**

Error in corclust(iris[, -5], iris[, 5], mincor = 0.5) : 
  unused argument (mincor = 0.5)

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes up because you are specifying "mincor" as an argument for the `corclust` function, which does not use it. Instead just try:

```
plot(corclust(iris[,-5]))
```

That should give you the cluster dendogram. However, the iris dataset after removing the species column contains no factor variables so you might want to try it out with another dataset.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several issues:

1. The `mincor` argument belongs to the `plot` function call, not `corclust`.
2. You provide a `data.frame` and a `vector` to `corclust` when it only takes a `data.frame` (see `?corclust`).
3. I assume you don't need the 5th column for `corclust` because it's categorial.

So that gives you:

```
plot(corclust(iris[,-5]), mincor=0.5)
```